# Alternative for the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 3160NGW

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I got a Dell Inspiron 7547 with Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160, but in all forums, all users have issues with this Wifi+Bluetooth Card, I want to change it but not sure what type of connection or slot has in it.

[This is the card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V7ZJGQ6) but dont know if this is pci-express, half pci or any other type for the wifi, some people suggest Intel AC 7265 but I dont need so much technology just Wifi b/g + Bluetooth. Any suggestion what type or kind of wifi card should I get/look?

Edit1: 
I attached the image of the card, I open the Laptop and take a picture of the card itself
[Image of the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XveBx.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the problems that other user's have reported?  I hate to the person to tell you this, but the reason the card has problems, is because of the design of the laptop itself.  Your not likely to have much luck with another Mini PCI Express wireless adapter.  *The card you are asking about is the NGFF version of the card you want to replace.*  **It is not compatible with your hardware.**

Comment: If you want confirmation about the compatability about any devices, in the form of an answer, you need to provide us the exact model number that is on the part.

Comment: NGFF is related to the M.2 form factor which is PCIe (and SATA) based standard.  In this case a NGFF based wireless adaptor would be PCIe.  The reason the model number is required is because you have asked for an alternative to a specific product (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160), asked about what basically is the M.2 version of that product (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160NGW), then don't seem certain of anything.  My research discovered that there are two versions of the `Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160` one is Mini-PCIe the other is NGFF

Comment: The model is 3160NGW I update the post and added a picture

Comment: @Ramhound yeah it looks like the NGFF, do you suggest another brand? or just another model? looks like Intel manage a lot of models of NGFF

Answer (score 0):

That is a Mini PCI-E Laptop, Full Card. There are various options with Intel being on the most expensive side. Atheros or Broadcom are two good options which do not break the bank.